# Setting iframe source url

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to add the src for an iframe. However, when I try to access the SourceResourceURL I am getting an error that says "Property 'mapURl' does not exist on type '{ branch: string; address: string; tel: string; fax: string; email: string; map_link: string; }'.ts(2339)"...see my code below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer,SafeResourceUrl,} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.page.scss'],
})
export class ContactPage implements OnInit {


  mapURl: SafeResourceUrl;

  slider = [
    {
      branch: 'Head Office',
      address: '58A Half Way Tree Road, Kingston 10',
      tel: '(876) 926-3590-4 or 926-3740-6',
      fax: '(876) 922-5996',
      email: 'jis@jis.gov.jm',
      map_link:"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3794.44245595098!2d-76.7950062846247!3d18.0046584894462!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8edb3fbadd465f91%3A0x2421cdae52664b88!2sJamaica%20Information%20Service!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sjm!4v1574292631365!5m2!1sen!2sjm",
    },
    {
      branch: 'Television Department',
      address: '5-9 South Odeon Avenue (Half-Way Tree), Kng 10',
      tel: '(876) 922-3317 or 922-8680-2 or (876) 922-8684',
      fax: '(876) 922-5996',
      email: 'media@jis.gov.jm',
      map_link:"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3794.2956337390224!2d-76.80091328462457!3d18.01147858924482!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8edb3f24924360b1%3A0x77894e7882659946!2sJamaica%20Information%20Service%20Television!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sjm!4v1574292677100!5m2!1sen!2sjm",
    },
    {
      branch: 'Regional Office',
      address: 'NHT Building 42 B-C Union Street, Montego Bay',
      tel: '(876) 952-0544',
      fax: '(876) 922-5996',
      email: 'jis@jis.gov.jm',
      map_link:"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2675.8308615898427!2d-77.91857756949159!3d18.474765679968364!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8eda2a7b2092c601%3A0xb0f2a303ed0c04ea!2sNational%20Housing%20Trust%20-%20St.%20James%20Branch!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sjm!4v1574292573465!5m2!1sen!2sjm",
    }
  ];
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer) { }

  i=0;

  ionViewWillEnter(): void {
    for(let maps of this.slider){
      this.slider[this.i].mapURl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(maps.map_link);
      this.i++;
    }
  } 

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access 'mapURl' with as follow:

```
this.slider[this.i]['mapURl'] = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(maps.map_link);
```

and it will reboot this new field.

Good Luck!!!!